# Create a unique number based on date and autoincremented number

Tags: c#, .net, uniqueidentifier

I need to generate the incremental numbers based on date.
numbers created on a previous date (say  06-Jan-2014) should not be greater then numbers created on the coming dates (say 08-Jan-2014).
how to add it with date ?
I tried the down one but in few cases it is failing

```
static long num =1;
public long GetUniqueNumberAsPerDate(DateTime date)
{
    string dateStr = date.ToString("yyMMdd");
    long alwaysIncrementeduniqueNum = num + 1;

    return Convert.Int64(dateStr + alwaysIncrementeduniqueNum.ToString());
}
```

**Failing cases**

Date Passed : 2014-06-06
Num : 14
Number Created : 14060614

Date Passed : 2013-06-06
Num : 132
Number Created : 130606132 ( which is greater then 14060614)

The function can be called at same time by multiple applications. so the dateTime (even milliseconds) can be same
Any solution to this problem

Comment: I don't understand. Why no just check your `date` is less than `08-Jan-2014` or not?

Comment: @SonerGönül: that date was just for example, my mistake. editing

Comment: What's wrong with using `DateTime.Now.Ticks`?

Comment: it can generate duplicate values @Niklas

Comment: @Niklas: yes, dotctor is right

Comment: My 2 Cents, why not try a mechanism like Time Since Epoch? (amount of seconds passed since 1/1/1970), or is it an absolute must that you must be able to identify the date in the number you generate?

Comment: @ShivangMIttal - Even if you lock it in a thread and have it sleeping for a short time?

Comment: should it be incremental per application instance or it should be incremental even if you restart the program?

Comment: @dotctor: incremental logic is actually coming from another logic, for the sake of simplicity i have added it as static. I ensure it will always return incremental number regardless of the application and restart program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that your running number (alwaysincrementeduniquenumber) varies in the range from 1 to 1000. And when you do a string concatenation the final number will have less or more digits.

You could do something like

```
   const long k = 1000000;
   long value = long.Parse(dateStr) * k + alwaysIncrementeduniqueNum;
```

Assuming that you do not produce more than `K` records per day, this should guarantee that you don't have this problem.

Comment: I didn't understood how it willbe unique? so for same date, there would be many calls to this method GetUniqueNumberAsPerDate(). even milliseconds can be same. so then number will not be unique. please correct if i am wrong

Comment: Oops: Not done :) Your own example is 130606132 vs 14060614, The problem is not related to milli seconds, but the running number part being respectively 132 and 14. Since you use string concatenation this produces a number of 9 and 8 digits respectively. And then the number for year 2013 is biggest. Using my approach you would get 130606000132 and 140606000014 which would test ok.

Comment: The point is simply that you must force the date part to become the most significant part of the produced number.

Comment: I assume that you will increment the number. It is pseudo-code pointing you at the right direction. You should probably also make the code thread safe.

Comment: A more complete (but untested) solution could be https://gist.github.com/faester/6eef960ae990cc52c311

Answer (score 1):

```
    public long GetUniqueNumberAsPerDate(DateTime date)
    {
        double dateStr = date.ToOADate();
        dateStr *= 1000000;
        long alwaysIncrementeduniqueNum = num + 1;
        string uniqueNumber = alwaysIncrementeduniqueNum + " " + dateStr;

        return long.Parse(uniqueNumber);
    }
```

i think this should work, it first converts the date into a decimal number which is then muliplied to get rid of the decimals, and then the incrementing number is just added at the front as a string.

You can switch this aregment (date number first) so that the date number will always be bigger at a later date

Comment: how it willbe unique? for same datestr(  with same milliseconds ) it will return duplicate results

Comment: arent you using your increment number for that? The alwaysIncrementeduniqueNum should be increased everytime this function is called

Comment: Correct, faester suggest same solution. up 1

Answer (score 1):

> I need to generate the incremental numbers based on date. numbers created on a previous date should not be greater then numbers created on the coming dates.

According to this requirement you can simply take

```
date.Ticks
```

It provides a number that is strictly increasing with the `DateTime`.

If you want to avoid equal numbers on the same tick, you can add

```
Thread.Sleep(16);
```

Windows' timer interrupt ticks at 64 Hz.
This would however imply that you cannot generate more than 64 values per second.

Comment: it can generate duplicate values

Comment: Yes, for two dates taken at the exact same tick (20ms AFAIR), but he does not mention that this is forbidden.

Comment: If you lock it in a thread and have it sleep for a short time it should work, right?

Comment: @Niklas: Yes, it will work but i was wondering if there is any other solution possible for it. I looks like a logical problem to me

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have incremental number on a machine you can use this class

```
public class IncrementalNumberGenerator
{
    private readonly string _path;
    private readonly EventWaitHandle _waitHandle; 

    public IncrementalNumberGenerator(string path)
    {
        _path = path;
        _waitHandle =  new EventWaitHandle(true, EventResetMode.AutoReset, Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
        if (!File.Exists(_path))
            File.WriteAllText(_path,"0");
    }

    public ulong Next()
    {
        try
        {
            _waitHandle.WaitOne();
            var currentValue = ulong.Parse(File.ReadAllText(_path));
            File.WriteAllText(_path, (currentValue + 1).ToString());
            return currentValue + 1;
        }
        finally
        {
            _waitHandle.Set();
        }
    }
}
```

this will use a named wait handle to synchronize over different threads and processes.

use it like

```
var ing = new IncrementalNumberGenerator(@"c:\data\temp\synch");
```

and call `Next` when you need new number. By using this class you can get incremental number even if you have multiple instances of your application running or even if your application restarted.